# Migrating from an old OS X 10.6 Server

Tags: network, user-account, osx-server, migration

I need a little help with migrating from an old OS X 10.6 Server.

It's a Mac Pro that currently runs the old Server Admin and Workgroup Manager software. We have over 1000 users with their data stored on the local hard drives. These accounts are setup as Home Network Accounts (not Mobile accounts) in the LDAPv3 Open Directory, their data is shared via NFS.

So with this current setup using a truly outdated server and our client machines running 10.8 (the last OS to support network accounts coming from 10.6), it kinda works the way we need it to - each client machine is bound to the OD and is set to display a login window. The client can login with their credentials and their network share will be automatically mounted. It's like you're logging into a local account - you get to see your desktop, all your files are in the right folders, all the local apps remember what you last opened etc. This is the functionality we need to keep.

One of the main issues I've run into is that the new Server app only allows the creation of Local Directory Accounts where the user's folder is stored on the local hard drive. This isn't viable if you're planning on a Mac Mini server. So I found a way to edit the advanced account settings per user and tell the Server app to look at external storage instead. Which leads to this messy setup per user:

- Create new Local Directory user
- In Terminal, copy /Users/newuser to /EXT/Users/newuser
- In Server app, open Advanced Settings for newuser
- Change Home Directory from /Users/newuser to /EXT/Users/newuser
- Change Share Point URL to afp://server.com/Volumes/EXT/Users

Then I’d have to change permissions for newuser to allow myself read & write access in order to move all of their old data to their newly created home folder, remove myself when I’m done and set permissions again so they’d have read & write access.

Doing this per user feels like an absolute nightmare. And another reason why all users need to be created from scratch is that we’d like to move from NFS to APFS.

Are there any scripts that could automate this process? Any login hooks that would be useful? Or just an easier way to do this altogether?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. https://superuser.com/questions/1661911/migrating-from-an-old-os-x-10-6-server